# Read only files cannot be deleted in android using C remove()

Tags: android, c, file-io

I am writing unit tests for my code in android. These automated unit tests are supposed to run on Android.

One of my test cases is creating the file in Generic read mode, **-r--r--r-** and later removing it using `remove()` but `remove()` is failing. Upon investigation, I figured out that the failure is because the file is read-only.

As a workaround I am using `chmod()` to explicitly change the permission and then deleting it.

My question is,

1. Why can't we delete read-only files? Is it because we have read-only access to the owner as well?
2. Is there any better workaround to what I am doing?

Comment: Changing the permissions on a file, (assuming you have the privilege to do so), to enable its deletion does not sound like a 'workaround' to me.  It's just business as usual?

Comment: It is somewhat of an anomaly of the Unix filesystem (and inherited by Linux) that deleting a file does not require write access to the file (but rather, merely write access to the containing directory).  Many other operating systems do not work that way, and it sounds from your description as if Android is one of them.

Comment: I guess`selinux` is involved somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need write permissions to delete a file, as you change it's content deleting it. When you delete a file, you are actually changing a reference count on this file, stored in your file system (e.g. EXT3, EXT4), you are also changing it's deletion time, and a few other informations.
To delete a file, you need to use chmod to grant write access to an user.